# Got an error make DDL & insert data on some cases in oracle11g

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I created a training table and data to put in it.

**DDL**

```
It`s privacy data so I deleted it
```

The table is created normally, but the following error occurs from the insert data after the company, that is, when the value is put in the employee data.

error - ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.SYS_C007017) violated - parent key not found

Is there any value I set incorrectly when I created the table?
And does my table fit the conditions?

Which data should be inserted before modification? ..

thank you for reading

my version -> oracle 11g

Comment: "For an insert statement, this ORA-02291 error is common when you are trying to insert a child without a matching parent, as defined by a foreign key constraint.  In that case, you need to add the parent row to the table and then re-insert your child table row."

Comment: @Know-nothing I entered the data value of the company table, but I don't know why the employee data value is not entered. The city column of the company table written as a reference exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary key of table COMPANY is COMPANY_NAME, for which you have inserted these values:

- SAMSUNG
- LG
- POSCO
- KIA
- SK

Table EMPLOYEE has a foreign key `(city) references company`, which means values in EMPLOYEE.CITY must match existing values in COMPANY.COMPANY_NAME.

You are trying to insert 'Soeul' into EMPLOYEE.CITY.  Since this does not match any value of COMPANY.COMPANY_NAME, you get the constraint violation.

Comment: where is the 'Soeul' ?..  everything as I see it`s all the 'Seoul'

Comment: @beenz here is the 'Soeul': `insert into employee values ('Youngbin', 'S-1', 'Seoul')`